# C++ Linux Google Protobuf + boost::asio Cannot Parse

Tags: c++, linux, tcp, boost-asio, protocol-buffers

I am trying to send a Google Protobuf message over a boost::asio socket via TCP. I recognize that TCP is a streaming protocol and thus I am performing length-prefixing on the messages before they go through the socket. I have the code working, but it only appears to work some of the time, even though I'm repeating the same calls and not changing the environment. On occasion I will receive the following error:

> [libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "xxx" because it is missing required fields: Name, ApplicationType, MessageType

The reason is easy to understand, but I cannot single out why this only occurs sometimes and parses just fine the majority of the time. It is very easy to duplicate the error by just having a single client talking to the server and simply restarting the processes.

Below are the socket code snippets.

`const int TCP_HEADER_SIZE = 8;`

**Sender:**

```
bool Write(const google::protobuf::MessageLite& proto) {
    char header[TCP_HEADER_SIZE];
    int size = proto.ByteSize();
    char data[TCP_HEADER_SIZE + size];
    sprintf(data, "%i", size);
    proto.SerializeToArray(data+TCP_HEADER_SIZE, size);
    boost::asio::async_write(Socket, 
                             boost::asio::buffer(data, TCP_HEADER_SIZE + size),
                             boost::bind(&TCPSender::WriteHandler, 
                                         this, _1, _2));
}
```

**Receiver:**

```
std::array<char, TCP_HEADER_SIZE> Header;
std::array<char, 8192> Bytes;

void ReadHandler(const boost::system::error_code &ec, 
                 std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    if(!ec) {
        int msgsize = atoi(Header.data());
        if(msgsize > 0) {
            boost::asio::read(Socket, boost::asio::buffer(Bytes,static_cast<std::size_t>(msgsize)));
            ReadFunc(Bytes.data(), msgsize);
        }
        boost::asio::async_read(Socket, boost::asio::buffer(Header, TCP_HEADER_SIZE),
                                boost::bind(&TCPReceiver::ReadHandler, this, _1, _2));
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Server::ReadHandler::" << ec.message() << '\n';
    }
}
```

**ReadFunc:**

```
void HandleIncomingData(const char *data, const std::size_t size) {
    xxx::messaging::CMSMessage proto;
    proto.ParseFromArray(data, static_cast<int>(size));
}
```

I should mention that I need this to be as fast as possible, so any optimizations would be very much appreciated as well.

Comment: Skimming, I don't see an obvious problem, but regarding optimizations, check out `MessageLite::SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray()`. Your current code actually computes `ByteSize()` twice. Also try compiling in debug mode (without `-DNDEBUG`) if you haven't already; then required fields will be checked at serialization time (not just parse time), which will let you rule out bugs on that end.

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't realize that there were such optimizations already built into protobuf. I will have to look into using the CodedOutputStream a bit more, but I think that might be the right track.

Comment: If you look at the definitions in message_lite.cc you can get a sense of what the various serialization/parse methods do under the hood without too much work. Generally you shouldn't need to use the "coded streams" directly if you understand what the wrapper methods do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program invokes undefined behavior as it fails to meet a lifetime requirement for [`boost::asio::async_write()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html)'s `buffers` parameter:

> [...] ownership of the underlying memory blocks is retained by the caller, which must guarantee that they remain valid until the handler is called.

Within the `Write()` function, `boost::asio::async_write()` will return immediately, and potentially cause `data` to go out of scope before the asynchronous write operation has completed.  To resolve this, consider expanding the life of the underlying buffer, such as by associating the buffer with the operation and performing cleanup in the handler, or making the buffer a data member on `TCPSender`.

Comment: This was exactly it, I extended the lifetime of the buffer variable data and it has resolved the issue. It had skipped my mind that the async_write may not complete before leaving the function (although that's the whole point). Thanks so much!